# How to extract xml tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, xmltocsv

I am trying to extract the tags from this data:

```
[{"title":"Joshua Cohen","nid":"21706","type":"winner","changed":"1651960857","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"640"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A mordant, linguistically deft historical novel about the ambiguities of the Jewish-American experience, presenting ideas and disputes as volatile as its tightly-wound plot."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Netanyahus: An Account of a Minor and Ultimately Even Negligible Episode in the History of a Very Famous Family"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"New York Review Books"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/joshua-cohen"},{"title":"Louise Erdrich","nid":"21286","type":"winner","changed":"1623362816","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"632"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A majestic, polyphonic novel about a community\u2019s efforts to halt the proposed displacement and elimination of several Native American tribes in the 1950s, rendered with dexterity and imagination."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Night Watchman"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"Harper"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/louise-erdrich"},
```

But I cannot seem to get the tags; I am trying:

```
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
content = []
# Read the XML file
with open("file.xml", "r") as file:
    # Read each line in the file
    content = file.readlines()
    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")

result = bs_content.find_all("title")
print(result)
```

But I only get an empty []
Appreciate any help!

Comment: That 'data' appears to be a list of dictionaries, with incomplete closing tags? Where are you getting that data from? Does it come incomplete, or did you just posted it incomplete? Did you try reading it as a json object, and then dissecting it?

Comment: its from an API, sorry, yes, will try reading it as json object - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not XML its a JSON like structure, so simply iterate the `list` of dicts:

```
l = [{"title":"Joshua Cohen","nid":"21706","type":"winner","changed":"1651960857","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"640"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A mordant, linguistically deft historical novel about the ambiguities of the Jewish-American experience, presenting ideas and disputes as volatile as its tightly-wound plot."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Netanyahus: An Account of a Minor and Ultimately Even Negligible Episode in the History of a Very Famous Family"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"New York Review Books"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/joshua-cohen"},{"title":"Louise Erdrich","nid":"21286","type":"winner","changed":"1623362816","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"632"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A majestic, polyphonic novel about a community\u2019s efforts to halt the proposed displacement and elimination of several Native American tribes in the 1950s, rendered with dexterity and imagination."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Night Watchman"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"Harper"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/louise-erdrich"},]

for d in l:
    print(d['title'])
```

Or while you have a string just convert it before via `json.loads()`:

```
import json

l = '[{"title":"Joshua Cohen","nid":"21706","type":"winner","changed":"1651960857","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"640"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A mordant, linguistically deft historical novel about the ambiguities of the Jewish-American experience, presenting ideas and disputes as volatile as its tightly-wound plot."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Netanyahus: An Account of a Minor and Ultimately Even Negligible Episode in the History of a Very Famous Family"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"New York Review Books"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/joshua-cohen"},{"title":"Louise Erdrich","nid":"21286","type":"winner","changed":"1623362816","field_category":{"und":[{"tid":"219"}]},"field_year":{"und":[{"tid":"632"}]},"field_abbr_citation":{"und":[{"safe_value":"A majestic, polyphonic novel about a community\u2019s efforts to halt the proposed displacement and elimination of several Native American tribes in the 1950s, rendered with dexterity and imagination."}]},"field_location_text":[],"field_publication":{"und":[{"safe_value":"The Night Watchman"}]},"field_publisher":{"und":[{"safe_value":"Harper"}]},"field_teaser_thumbnail":[],"path_alias":"winners\/louise-erdrich"}]'

for d in json.loads(l):
    print(d['title'])
```

Output:

```
Joshua Cohen
Louise Erdrich
```